# Rewriting Pulp Constraint into Mathematical Equation

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm completely to Pulp and the mathematical aspect of optimization.
I found some code for my optimisation problem that does exactly what I need.
However, I have to rewrite the code into a mathematical formula, which I'm having a hard time with.

I want to solve a maximisation problem with Pulp:
`model = pulp.LpProblem("XY", pulp.LpMaximize)`

I'm trying to express to following contraints as a mathematical equation:

```
for hour_of_sim in range(1,time_span+1):     
            model += \
            initial_level \
            + pulp.LpAffineExpression(
                [(P_Charge['C_' + str(i)], 0.25)
                 for i in range(0,hour_of_sim)]) \
            - pulp.lpSum(
                P_Discharge[index]
                for index in('D_' + str(i)
                             for i in range(0,hour_of_sim)))\
            >= E_Min
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help rewrite the constraint into a math equation like this: [Example Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbwT1.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give it a try, and post what you come up with and where you are stuck.  Hopefully you know what it is doing, so that will be a start.  Here is the doc for `LpAffineExpression` which is the only real tricky part and not clear on inspection:  https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/pulp.html#pulp.LpAffineExpression